# get the full string, while having format and args c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am using c++ 11. I want to write a function that gets formatted string, and the args (don't know how many, needs to be variadic) and returns the full string.

for example:

```
format = "TimeStampRecord Type=%u Version=%u OptimizeBlockID=%u WriteBlockID=%u Timestamp=%lu"

INDEX_RECORD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP = 3;
FORAMT_VERSION = 1;
optimizeBlockId = 549;
writeBlockId = 4294967295;
timestamp = 1668;
```

and the return value is a string that looks like:

```
"TimeStampRecord Type=3 Version=1 OptimizeBlockID=549 WriteBlockID=4294967295 Timestamp=1668"
```

any efficient way to do so?

Comment: What, you mean [`std::snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)?

Comment: [`autosprintf`](http://doc.gnu-darwin.org/libasprintf/autosprintf.html), [`Boost.Format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/format/)

Comment: What about http://abel.web.elte.hu/mpllibs/safe_printf/index.html

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg i don't know what is the size of the buffer

Comment: You know the length of the format, you know the number and type of arguments. That means you can easily create a `std::string` object with enough space for the maximum values of the arguments, and use it as the destination in the call to `snprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/doc/format.html).  Or good old `sprintf()`:

```
char buf[1000];
int bytes = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format, INDEX_RECORD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    FORMAT_VERSION, optimizeBlockId, writeBlockId, timestamp);
assert(bytes < sizeof(buf));
string result(buf, min(sizeof(buf), bytes)); // now you have a C++ string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use snprintf as suggested above.
In case you want to implement it by your own or use your own placeholder:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

void formatImpl(std::string& fmtStr) {
}

template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
void formatImpl(std::string& fmtStr, T arg, Ts... args) {
  // Deal with fmtStr and the first arg
  formatImpl(fmtStr, args...);
}

template<typename ...Ts>
std::string format(const std::string& fmtStr, Ts ...args) {
  std::string fmtStr_(fmtStr);
  formatImpl(fmtStr_, args...);
  return fmtStr_;
}


int main() {
  std::string fmtStr = "hello %your_placeholder world";
  std::cout << format(fmtStr, 1, 'a') << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/hFwiS0